# Difference between Spring rest and Spring Data

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am using Neo4j SDN for grails , What is the difference between SDN rest and  ('org.springframework.data:spring-data-neo4j-rest:3.2.0.RELEASE')
Simple SDN 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-neo4j:3.2.0.RELEASE'

Answer (score 0):

Spring Data Neo4j - REST is a wrapper around the Neo4j REST APIs to have SDN talk to a Neo4j Server.

The currentl implementation is not really good, the next Milestone 3.3.0.M1 will address a lot of that.